# Snackbar stack will always show only the last snackbar

Tags: android, android-design-library, android-snackbar

The `Snackbar.make(...).show()` will only show the last snackbar unlike toast the other snackbars are gone.

```
for(int i = 1;i < 11;i++) {  
   Snackbar.make(..., "number: " + i, Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

Sometimes when the snackbar should show after network task and one should show before network task, the seconds snackbar is never shown.

Im using a coordinatorlayout.

Comment: Snackbars are not meant for logging purposes, for that use `Log.d`

Comment: this was just a example when becuase of network delay 2 snackbars shows in the same time

Comment: @pskink Are you serious? Lol

Comment: @TheRealChx101 yes I am

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I implemented now my own queue:

```
protected ArrayList<Snackbar> mSnackbarList = new ArrayList<>();

protected Snackbar.Callback mCallback = new Snackbar.Callback() {
    @Override
    public void onDismissed(Snackbar snackbar, int event) {
        mSnackbarList.remove(snackbar);
        if (mSnackbarList.size() > 0)
           displaySnackbar(mSnackbarList.get(0));
    }
};

public void addQueue(Snackbar snackbar){
    setLayoutParams(snackbar);
    snackbar.setCallback(mCallback);
    boolean first = mSnackbarList.size() == 0;
    mSnackbarList.add(snackbar);
    if(first)
        displaySnackbar(snackbar);
}

public void displaySnackbar(Snackbar snackbar){
    snackbar.show();
}
```

Comment: Thanks. This works exceptionally well so far. They want you to use snackbar.addCallback(mCallback)  as snackbar.setCallback(mCallback) is deprecated.

Answer (score -1):

Please refer the Android components docs:

> Snackbars automatically time out from the screen. For usability reasons,  snackbars should not contain the only way to access a core use case. They  should not be persistent **or be stacked**, as they are above other elements on screen ([Source](https://www.google.com/design/spec/components/snackbars-toasts.html#snackbars-toasts-usage))

Comment: you think thats displaying after and before a network request is stacking?

Comment: wrong interpretation of stacked. this means "visually" stacked. We are trying to solve "logically" stacked. If what you say is true, then why does Android Compose have a queue system for Snackbar? link: https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/material/SnackbarHostState#showSnackbar(kotlin.String,kotlin.String,androidx.compose.material.SnackbarDuration)
quote "Shows or queues to be shown a Snackbar at the bottom of the Scaffold at which this state is attached and suspends until snackbar is disappeared."